# Consulta sin registros repetidos según el MAX(Nombre_Campo) en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transact-sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla. Necesito traer sin repetir registros el Top (20) de los cursos con mayor número de miembros.

Cuando hablo de repetir registros es que el nombre del curso no esté repetido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT TOP(20) Id, CourseName, NumberCompany,DateUpdate, 
       FROM CompanyInCourse 
       GROUP BY Id, CourseName, NumberCompany,  DateUpdate,  
       ORDER BY NumberCompany DESC
```

Comment: No te sirve el `SELECT DISTINCT TOP(20) ...` ?

Comment: Devuelve nombres de cursos repetidos por que la fecha de actualizacion es diferente para el mismo curso

Comment: Si ese fuera el caso, habría que indicar cuáles cursos deben estar; porque claro, la fecha de actualización es distinta y a su vez el curso repetido debe ser parte de aquel grupo con mayor número de miembros. Tienes que indicar de alguna forma qué registro de esos cursos repetidos deseas mantener en la consulta. Te doy un ejemplo; si haces una sub-query e indicas que de aquellos cursos solo requieres el último o el antepenúltimo o si encuentra cursos repetidos, te devuelva el que tiene una fecha mayor a o menor a... cosas así.

Comment: La consulta debe devolver Nombres de cursos sin repetir  ordenados por  los que tengan mayor Numero de miembros  de forma descendente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Te comparto el [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4140766dfd54b028a19f2f8bc8fc0b49) donde está resuelto paso por paso.

Se tiene que hacer mediante una sub-query en la que, como bien explicas, hay que hacer uso de `MAX()`.

La consulta que tienes se resume en el siguiente resultado:

[image: InitialResult]

Modificando tu consulta, queda la siguiente:

```sql
SELECT TOP(20) id, course_name, number_member, date_update
FROM MOCK_DATA MG
WHERE number_member = (SELECT MAX(number_member) 
                       FROM MOCK_DATA 
                       WHERE course_name=MG.course_name)
ORDER BY number_member DESC
```

Y el resultado final sería:
[image: ResultadoFinal]

Comment: Pruebo y te comento